# Failed to find : com.android.support:appcompat-v7:0.0 after the support library installing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've found Android Studio is very buggable and weird. - I use 0.8.14

I imported the solution from https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout

Author used to built the solution with the Android Studio. 
Project contains of library and sample Project with several Activities.

When I build the solution, I've got

```
Error:Failed to find: com.android.support:support-v4:20

Error:Failed to find: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:0.0
```

I have an options to install the Android Support Repository - I do it but everything stay the same.

My Android SDK :

[image]